# Is there a good program to generate gifs from a wmv file?

Tags: windows, video-conversion, gif, wmv

I want to generate gif files from wmv movie files. I am hoping that it can generate from a given section in the movie file with options of how many images are in the gif. Can you help me?

This is for Windows XP

Answer (score 2):

i've used [GiftedMotion](http://www.onyxbits.de/giftedmotion) to create .gifs from movies before. on a Mac, so i've used QuickTime 7's ability to export a selection as a group of images and then imported those into giftedmotion to tweak the .gif.

given that you asked for .wmv specific instructions, i'll assume you're on windows, so the Mac OS X stuff is of little use to you. GiftedMotion is a java app though, so provided you can find a way to export the .wmv to a sequence of images, that should help you create the final product.